# What is new in .Net framework 3.5?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5

I try to keep it very simple.
All I have seen in .Net 3.5fx is language upgrades i.e C# 3.0, VB.Net 9, still core CLR is based 2.0fx. I really did not find any new features (LINQ is again language feature).

Is .Net framewors 3.5 just like fixed version of .Net 3.0 framework ?

I really failed to find some thing new in core framework :(

Comment: Even if LINQ is just a language feature, it still requires support in the core libraries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. System.Data.Linq.dll – The implementation for LINQ to SQL.
2. System.Xml.Linq.dll – The implementation for LINQ to XML.
3. System.AddIn.dll, System.AddIn.Contract.dll – New AddIn (plug-in) model.
4. System.Net.dll – Peer to Peer APIs.
5. System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll – Wrapper for Active Directory APIs.
6. System.Management.Instrumentation.dll – WMI 2.0 managed provider (combined with System.Management namespace in System.Core.dll).
7. System.WorkflowServices.dll and System.ServiceModel.Web.dll – WF and WCF enhancements (for more on WF + WCF in v3.5 follow links from here).
8. System.Web.Extensions.dll – The implementation for ASP.NET AJAX (for more web enhancements, follow links from here) plus also the implementation of Client Application Services and the three ASP.NET 3.5 controls.
9. System.Core.dll – In addition to the LINQ to Objects implementation, this assembly includes the following: HashSet, TimeZoneInfo, Pipes, ReaderWriteLockSlim, System.Security.*, System.Diagnostics.Eventing.* and System.Diagnostics.PerformanceData.
10. System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll – The implementation of LINQ to DataSet.
11. System.Windows.Presentation.dll –WPF support for the System.AddIn mentioned of point 3 above.
12. System.VisualC.STLCLR.dll – STL development in the managed world.

Comment: I used many of these... Thanks for the list

Answer (score 1):

How about this "[What's New in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332048.aspx)"? Ain't Google grand...

Comment: Can't believe this was voted down without even a comment... poor show

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#.NET_Framework_3.5), it's has a lot of items. I guess it's up to you as to what you think qualifies as "new". Of course, `.net 4.0` is going to shake things up in a big way on the "core new features" side.

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of enhancements in `.NET Framework 3.5`:

- CLR Enhancements: Although the CLR uses the same model as 2.0.
- Compiler Enhancements: New VB.NET 9.0 compiler and support for changes to C# 3.0 like
  expression trees, lambda methods, extension methods, static reference for anonymous types etc.
- LINQ: Probably the most revolutionary change in the 3.5 framework. LINQ to XML, LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Objects and LINQ to Datasets. Along with functional programming, LINQ is an outlook change to programming in C#.
- Performance Improvements: Quite a few performance improvements have been made in 3.5. ADO.NET gets paging support as well as synchronization from caches at local and server datastores. Also performance improvements for multicore CPUs.
- Networking changes: Peer-to-peer networking stack, including a
  managed PNRP resolver.
- Windows Information APIs: New wrappers for WMI and Active Directory Services. WMI 2.0 gets a managed provider.
- ASP.NET: New implementation of Client Application Services as well as
  3 new ASP.NET controls. Also AJAX programming for ASP.NET is easier
  and better performing.
- Windows Communication Foundation: WCF now works with POX and JSON
  data.
- Windows Presentation Foundation: Newer plugin model for creating AddIns. SilverLight CLR is also part of the .Net Framework.
- Misc: The C/C++ get a standard template libarary (STL) so that these
  languages can use share .NET libraries

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

In `.net 3.5`, you can use `Lambda` and `Linq` to operate data.

Here is a demo:

```
int[] i={1,2,3,4};
var a=(from a in i where a>2).toArray();
```

We get a array which contain 3 and 4

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=333325FD-AE52-4E35-B531-508D977D32A6&displaylang=en#Overview)

> - Deep integration of Language
>     Integrated Query (LINQ) and data
>     awareness. This new feature will let
>     you write code written in LINQ-enabled
>     languages to filter, enumerate, and
>     create projections of several types of
>     SQL data, collections, XML, and
>     DataSets by using the same syntax.
> - ASP.NET AJAX lets you create more efficient, more interactive, and
>     highly-personalized Web experiences
>     that work across all the most popular
>     browsers.
> - New Web protocol support for building WCF services including AJAX,
>     JSON, REST, POX, RSS, ATOM, and
>     several new WS-* standards.
> - Full tooling support in Visual Studio 2008 for WF, WCF, and WPF,
>     including the new workflow-enabled
>     services technology.